# Azure DevOps remote branches are not visible in one repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

The list of actions I do and the result:

1. Locally I have a `master` branch and I have it on a remote.
2. I create a `dev/test` branch locally
3. I push it to the remote
4. On the Azure DevOps website I can see that branch appeared in Branches in the "Mine" tab.
5. If I try to fetch and list branches from Visual Studio or git bash only the `master` branch is visible.

   ```
   $ git branch -r  
     origin/HEAD -> origin/master   
     origin/master
   ```

The only way I found to show all remote branches is:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin
08e2d2e3d332b607cef7cc85068b7eb1459d6d82        refs/heads/dev/test
04465a9f213757430aea00b77c4841c2e35ec8dc        refs/heads/master
```

The problem is that I cannot checkout/pull/merge the branch that I don't see.

I tried to create a new repository and do the same actions, everything is visible as usual and as it should be. So the issue only with a specific repository.

My question is, what should I check? How to make the remote branch visible?

Actions I tried:

`git fetch` does absolutely nothing.

```
$ git branch -vv
* dev/test      ada4e0e commmitMessage 
  master        ada4e0e [origin/master] commmitMessage
```

It doesn't show remote tracking, I tried to add it

```
$ git branch -u origin/dev/test
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/dev/test' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

So I did what was suggested

```
$ git push -u
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'dev/test' set up to track remote branch 'dev/test' from 'origin'.
```

And checked again

```
$ git fetch
From https://dev.azure.com/company/repo/_git/repo
 * branch            dev/test   -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git branch -vv
* dev/test      ada4e0e commmitMessage 
  master        ada4e0e [origin/master] commmitMessage 

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Comment: Can you try to reclone the remote repository?

Comment: I tried as well, I got only master

Comment: Can you reproduce with a new branch on the concerned repository?

Comment: Yes, a new branch on this repository have the same behavior

Comment: Maybe a branch security setting on ADO.

Comment: Any ideas on how to check that? I'm the only person with admin rights on the repository and I haven't been doing any changes in settings for years.

Comment: On the tab branch, you can open branch security settings.

Comment: Hi @hiichaki, Open Visual Studio->Click Team Explorer->Click Home->Sync->Click the button Fetch. Could you try it and then kindly share the result here?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, VS shows the same after sync and fetch. I assume something is wrong with the config of the repository but I don't know what to check in there.

Comment: Hi @hiichaki, `VS shows the same after sync and fetch`, you could see the branch `dev/test` in the VS after Click the button Fetch, right?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT, I don't see `origin/dev/test` anywhere. Only `git ls-remote --heads origin` shows it. Local `dev/test` I see in both VS and git console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution. The repository was connected via HTTPS.
Switching to SSH solved all the issues.

The step by step instruction in [microsoft docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

**Step 1**
In Bash:
$ ssh-keygen -C "your@email.com".

**Step 2**
Add public key to Azure DevOps.

**Step 3**
Move generated private key file to `C:\Users\{username}\.ssh`.
On the same location create `config` file with

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privateKey     
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

[image]

**Step 4**
Clone using SSH link.

Done!

Comment: Having the issue over SSH....